# SPI registor read write application in UEFI bootloader

Tags: x86, bootloader, spi, uefi, gnu-efi

I am new in UEFI system. I want to read/write the registors over SPI interface but not found any APIs or application in UEFI.

It would be helpful if anyone can suggest the sample application or APIs for the same.

Thanks in advance,
Hardik

Answer (score 0):

UEFI does not specify anything about SPI. Many UEFI implementations are however based on the [PI specification](http://www.uefi.org/sites/default/files/resources/PI_Spec_1_6.pdf) which describes an SPI protocol stack (chapter 18).